# Units display while in Orthographic Blender 2.8

Tags: 3d-view

Please tell me you can still display Units while in orthographic in Blender 2.8.

I don't like (or want) to use Overlays only in Edit mode. That is clunky.

If you don't know what I'm talking about:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

2.81 added this. I'm very happy.